# why TwitterApp give VerifyError?

Tags: android

I am Integrating twitter in my android App,There is an exception occure before opening lauching app stackTrace is as:-

```
   07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): java.lang.VerifyError: com.appstudioz.twitter.TwitterApp
    07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.appstudioz.bidnear.NewsFeed.onCreate(NewsFeed.java:44)
   07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
  07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
  07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
  07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
 07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
  07-26 16:01:34.004: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I am using this code:-

Button mbutton;

```
private TwitterApp mTwitter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
private String url;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "mdgzcl73NRkKaRzqVutQpA";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET="FVZwc6m4FZ5TbAU2uAfWhbxUMMcZ835Hp3VWBEF10";

private enum FROM {
    TWITTER_POST, TWITTER_LOGIN
};

private enum MESSAGE {
    SUCCESS, DUPLICATE, FAILED, CANCELLED
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo);//newsfeed);
    mbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.demo);
    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
         calltwitter();         
        }
    });
    mTwitter = new TwitterApp(NewsFeed.this, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);
    //setTabs();
}

private void calltwitter()
{


    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken())
    {
        try
        {
            String comment = "I found this App Send SuccessFully..?";
            String demo = "Hi ! Share Have been done ...";
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(demo);
                //mTwitter.updateStatus("rentfaster: "+demo+");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    else 
    {
        mTwitter.authorize();
    }


}


/**
 * Twitter Dialog Listner.
 */
//private TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() 

private TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {

    public void onError(String value) {
        mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
    }

    public void onComplete(String value) {

        String comment = "I found working fine";
        try
        {
            String demo = "Hi ! Share Have been done ...";
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(demo);
                //mTwitter.updateStatus("rentfaster: "+demo+");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
    }
};

private void setTabs()
{


}
```

before lauching app above exception occure .My requirment some data share on twitter but in first step I am facing this issue please someone suggest me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Twitter4j library for that and use below code for integrate twitter into your application.

MainActivity.java

```
private TwitterApp mTwitter;
    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "your consumer key"; 
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "your consumer secret key"; 

    private enum FROM {
        TWITTER_POST, TWITTER_LOGIN
    };

    private enum MESSAGE {
        SUCCESS, DUPLICATE, FAILED, CANCELLED
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);
        mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
        if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken() == true) {
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(TwitterApp.MESSAGE);
                postAsToast(FROM.TWITTER_POST, MESSAGE.SUCCESS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.getMessage().toString().contains("duplicate")) {
                    postAsToast(FROM.TWITTER_POST, MESSAGE.DUPLICATE);
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
        } else {
            mTwitter.authorize();
        }
    }

    private void postAsToast(FROM twitterPost, MESSAGE success) {
        switch (twitterPost) {
        case TWITTER_LOGIN:
            switch (success) {
            case SUCCESS:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                break;
            case FAILED:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        case TWITTER_POST:
            switch (success) {
            case SUCCESS:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Posted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                break;
            case FAILED:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Posting Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                break;
            case DUPLICATE:
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Posting Failed because of duplicate message...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(String value) {
            postAsToast(FROM.TWITTER_LOGIN, MESSAGE.FAILED);
            Log.e("TWITTER", value);
            mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String value) {
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(TwitterApp.MESSAGE);
                postAsToast(FROM.TWITTER_POST, MESSAGE.SUCCESS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.getMessage().toString().contains("duplicate")) {
                    postAsToast(FROM.TWITTER_POST, MESSAGE.DUPLICATE);
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
        }
    };
```

Add Following 3 Class into New Package "com.twitter.android"

Class 1:-(TwitterApp.java)

```
package com.twitter.android;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Window;


public class TwitterApp {
    private Twitter mTwitter;
    private TwitterSession mSession;
    private AccessToken mAccessToken;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mHttpOauthConsumer;
    private OAuthProvider mHttpOauthprovider;
    private String mConsumerKey;
    private String mSecretKey;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
    private TwDialogListener mListener;
    private Activity context;


    public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME   = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
    public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST     = "callback";
    public static final String  CALLBACK_URL      = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
    private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    private static final String TWITTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "Hello Everyone....";

    public TwitterApp(Activity context, String consumerKey, String secretKey) {
        this.context = context;

        mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        mSession = new TwitterSession(context);
        mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(context);

        mProgressDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        mSecretKey = secretKey;

        mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey,
                mSecretKey);

        String request_url=TWITTER_REQUEST_URL;
        String access_token_url=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL;
        String authorize_url=TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL;

        mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
                request_url,
                access_token_url,
                authorize_url);
        mAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();

        configureToken();
    }

    public void setListener(TwDialogListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void configureToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
            mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasAccessToken() {
        return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
    }

    public void resetAccessToken() {
        if (mAccessToken != null) {
            mSession.resetAccessToken();

            mAccessToken = null;
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mSession.getUsername();
    }

    public void updateStatus(String status) throws Exception {
        try {
            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void authorize() {
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Initializing ...");
        mProgressDlg.show();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String authUrl = "";
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(
                            mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);
                    what = 0;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler
                        .obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void processToken(String callbackUrl) {
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Finalizing ...");
        mProgressDlg.show();

        final String verifier = getVerifier(callbackUrl);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer,
                            verifier);

                    mAccessToken = new AccessToken(
                            mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(),
                            mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());

                    configureToken();

                    User user = mTwitter.verifyCredentials();

                    mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                    what = 0;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private String getVerifier(String callbackUrl) {
        String verifier = "";

        try {
            callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace("twitterapp", "http");

            URL url = new URL(callbackUrl);
            String query = url.getQuery();

            String array[] = query.split("&");

            for (String parameter : array) {
                String v[] = parameter.split("=");

                if (URLDecoder.decode(v[0]).equals(
                        oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER)) {
                    verifier = URLDecoder.decode(v[1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return verifier;
    }

    private void showLoginDialog(String url) {
        final TwDialogListener listener = new TwDialogListener() {

            public void onComplete(String value) {
                processToken(value);
            }

            public void onError(String value) {
                mListener.onError("Failed opening authorization page");
            }
        };

        new TwitterDialog(context, url, listener).show();
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();

            if (msg.what == 1) {
                if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                    mListener.onError("Error getting request token");
                else
                    mListener.onError("Error getting access token");
            } else {
                if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                    showLoginDialog((String) msg.obj);
                else
                    mListener.onComplete("");
            }
        }
    };

    public interface TwDialogListener {
        public void onComplete(String value);

        public void onError(String value);
    }
}
```

Class 2:- (TwitterDialog.java)

```
package com.twitter.android;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.twitter.android.TwitterApp.TwDialogListener;

public class TwitterDialog extends Dialog {

    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE = { 460, 260 };
    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT = { 280, 420 };
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    static final int MARGIN = 4;
    static final int PADDING = 2;
    private String mUrl;
    private TwDialogListener mListener;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private LinearLayout mContent;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private boolean progressDialogRunning = false;

    public TwitterDialog(Context context, String url, TwDialogListener listener) {
        super(context);

        mUrl = url;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

        mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

        mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());

        mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        setUpTitle();
        setUpWebView();

        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float[] dimensions = (display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()) ? DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT
                : DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE;

        addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f), (int) (dimensions[1]
                        * scale + 0.5f)));
    }

    private void setUpTitle() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        Drawable icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.twitter_icon);

        mTitle = new TextView(getContext());

        mTitle.setText("Twitter");
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xFFbbd7e9);
        mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
        mTitle.setCompoundDrawablePadding(MARGIN + PADDING);
        mTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);

        mContent.addView(mTitle);
    }

    private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());

        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);

        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }

    private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(TwitterApp.CALLBACK_URL)) {
                mListener.onComplete(url);

                TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();

                return true;
            } else if (url.startsWith("authorize")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            mListener.onError(description);
            TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
            progressDialogRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }
            progressDialogRunning = false;
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        progressDialogRunning = false;
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!progressDialogRunning){
            TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Class 3:- (TwitterSession.java)

```
package com.twitter.android;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.Context;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;

public class TwitterSession {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private Editor editor;

    private static final String TWEET_AUTH_KEY = "auth_key";
    private static final String TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY = "auth_secret_key";
    private static final String TWEET_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String SHARED = "Twitter_Preferences";

    public TwitterSession(Context context) {
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        editor = sharedPref.edit();
    }

    public void storeAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken, String username) {
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, accessToken.getToken());
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
        editor.putString(TWEET_USER_NAME, username);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public void resetAccessToken() {
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, null);
        editor.putString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, null);
        editor.putString(TWEET_USER_NAME, null);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return sharedPref.getString(TWEET_USER_NAME, "");
    }

    public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
        String token = sharedPref.getString(TWEET_AUTH_KEY, null);
        String tokenSecret = sharedPref.getString(TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY, null);

        if (token != null && tokenSecret != null)
            return new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

And Add Following Jar File as a Refrence Library to Your Project :-

1)     signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar

2)     signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar

3)     signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar

4)     twitter4j-core-2.1.6.jar

Comment: I thing your code and My code is same ,perhaps issue is not in this code.

Comment: @skt ok check it and if you have any query regarding this then tell me.

Comment: @skt but this code is working in my application & you are working in which API?

Comment: I am running on emulator set mdpi resolution,I think issue is  differnt,I am trying to figure out please you also figureout it ,if got please suggest me!

Comment: I have test it on both API 8 And 10 as well but same exception occure .

Comment: @hi Dipak let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14456/discussion-between-skt-and-dipak-keshariya)

Answer (score 2):

Just move you jar files from lib folder to libs. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its SDk problem,I did update my sdk.It's working fine